# Why can't I initialize an ifstream in the initializer list of the constructor of a class?

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class file_reader {

public:
    file_reader(const char* file_name) : file(ifstream(file_name)) { }

    char operator[](int index) const {
        file.seekg(index);
        return file.get();
    }

private:
    ifstream file;

};
```

I get an error: `'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private`. Seems like the code is trying to call a constructor higher in the hierarchy. Although `ifstream` has a constructor that takes a `const char*`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By creating a temporary `ifstream(file_name)` then initialising `file` from it, you're trying to invoke file's copy constructor, and this fails because that constructor is private where it is declared (in the base `ios_base`); streams cannot be copied.

I'm sure you meant to write this:

```
file_reader(const char* file_name) : file(file_name) { }
```

---

Remember, this:

```
struct T
{
   S object;
   type() : object(arg) {};
};
```

in terms of initialising a `S` is much like:

```
int main()
{
   S object(arg);
}
```

Comment: But isn't `file(file_name)` equivalent to `file = file_name` (which of course doesn't compile), while `file(ifstream(file_name))` is equivalent to `file = ifstream(file_name)` - which shouldn't invoke the copy constructor but the assignment operator?

Comment: No, neither of those things are equivalent to the other thing. The assignment operator has nothing to do with initialisation. `file(file_name)` in the member initialiser list is the analogue of `std::ifstream file(file_name)`.

Comment: So the initializer list always calls the constructors of the initialized objects with the given arguments?

Comment: Btw say I wanted to add a method that changes the stream to a different object (i.e. a setter). I can say `file = somethingelse`. But wouldn't that try to call the copy constructor? Or is that okay?

Comment: Also, does the code `private: ifstream file` already call the constructor of `ifstream`?

Comment: @user3150201 If you want to implement a setter, then you probably need to use a pointer and dynamically allocate your stream. But you can always `close()` it and (re) `open()` it instead

Comment: @user3150201: Yeah you won't be able to do that. You're better off having a function that provides a new filename, and then you can call `.close` and `.open` on the stream member. That would be a much better interface anyway: there's no need for the users of your class to have to worry about what mechanism is used to access the file, so a dumb setter is kinda inappropriate.